# pathfind() function not found in libgen library

Tags: linux, unix, porting

In Linux, I am getting error "undefined reference to 'pathfind' while linking objects in Makefile. libgen, libposix4 libraries are linked to create executable. These libraries are not present in Linux. This pathfind() function declaration is present in libgen.h in Unix but nowhere in Linux. And am not getting where it is defined in Unix too. I assume that its a library function of libgen or libposix4.  Is there any equivalent function in Linux or I need to write my own function to acheive the functionality of pathfind()?? also equivalent libraries for libgen and libposix4?

Comment: what is linux equivalent library files for libgen and libposix4