# pathfind command on not found on linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, system, porting

I am trying to compile a code with pathfind command. This command however is present on solaris and there is no problem. However when i port my code to linux, i found that this is not found. Is there any equivalent on linux or should i write a wrapper for this one? 
More specifically i am trying to search for named file in named directories. Any suggestions?

Found a similar question [pathfind() function not found in libgen library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419284/pathfind-function-not-found-in-libgen-library). this however was not answered.

Comment: The `libgen` library seems like a Solaris-specific library, without any direct corresponding library or function in Linux.

Comment: Are you open to running Linux's `find` command in a subordinate process?

Comment: You also might consider refactoring and using `glob()`

Comment: nope i am not using find command in the subordinate. can try glob() function. however just found that how easy and straight forward libgen function is. need to investigate more on glob

Comment: more specifically
` (ptr = pathfind((PATH,  cmd,  "rx"))`

this is how i had used in solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the information of the link that you provided, Linux glibc-headers (glibc-headers-2.24-4.fc25.x86_64 in Fedora 25) provides /usr/include/libgen.h , but there is no definition of pathfind function on libgen.h. So I suppose there is no pathfind function in Linux because I have not found any function similar to [Solaris pathfind](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36877/pathfind-3gen.html)

So I guess you should write your own function, [here](http://www.johnloomis.org/ece537/notes/Files/Examples/printdir.html) you can find an approach.

I hope it helps.